# How to change only a certain character using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to change the + to - when toggled. The code is set up at
http://jsfiddle.net/B65Ht/

HTML

```
<a class="expandB" href="#">
   <h3>Advocacy + </h3>
</a>
<div class="content">
    Content goes here
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').hide();
    $("a.expandB").click(function() {  
        $(this).toggleClass("expandB").next().slideToggle("slow", function(){

       // script to toggle between + and -
     });

return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor/Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});


});​
```

​

Comment: The link i posted below was the first result in google and it contains a similar answer if not the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyk5K/)

You could do something like this:

```
 $("a.expandB").click(function() {

        var $a = $(this);            
        var $h3 = $a.find('h3');             
        $(this).toggleClass("expandB").next().slideToggle("slow", function() {
             var text = $h3.text();
             $a.hasClass('expandB') ? $h3.text(text.replace('-', '+')) : $h3.text(text.replace('+', '-')); 
        });
        // Toggles the text from expand to Collapse
       return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });
```

Comment: Thanks gabe, it works but the font size changes. How do I make sure h3 is still there. Update on http://jsfiddle.net/tWKRg/1/

Comment: I figured it out. I added $text("<h3>" + text + "</h3>"); after the variable is decelared. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to this one, so your answer will probably also be similar:

[jQuery .click() .toggle() - change display and swap character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006833/jquery-click-toggle-change-display-and-swap-character)

Answer (score 0):

No need for extra classes. Just swap via `.text()`;

```
$("a.expandB").click(function() {  

    $('span', this).text( $('span').text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');

    $(this).toggleClass("expandB").next().slideToggle("slow");    

    return false;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/aZaBe/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.expandB").click(function() {  
    var t=$(this);
    t.toggleClass("expandB").next()
    .slideToggle("slow", function(){
        if(t.hasClass('expandB')) $('h3', t).html('Advocacy +'); 
        else $('h3', t).html('Advocacy -'); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/B65Ht/2/)